# Block to accept and send email to specific domains

Tags: email, spam

I have a problem with my blog because a lot of emails are sent to one of these emails (different account some domain):

- gemmasmith.co.uk
- jenniferlawrence.uk
- b-mail.online
- katykahn.co.uk
- sarahconner.co.uk
- marymarshall.co.uk

I don't understand why the blog is sending all those emails. So, I tried to block the registration for those domains. First, I added in the function.php of the theme the following code

```
// prevent user registration in wordpress from specific domain
function wpcs_disable_email_domain ( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    list( $email_user, $email_domain ) = explode( '@', $user_email );
    if ( strpos($email_domain, 'b-mail.online') != false || 
         strpos($email_domain, 'dynainbox.com') != false || 
         strpos($email_domain, 'gemmasmith.co.uk') != false ||
         strpos($email_domain, 'marymarshall.co.uk') != false ||
         strpos($email_domain, 'katykahn.co.uk') != false || 
         strpos($email_domain, 'roastedtastyfood.com') != false
    ) {
        $errors->add( 'email_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Domain not allowed.', 'my_domain' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'wpcs_disable_email_domain', 10, 3 );
```

but the emails are still sending. Then, I tried different plug-in like Ban Hammer or WP Security. Nothing.

Could you help me to understand how to block all those emails to these domains?

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` will return `0` for a positive match at the start of a string, so your condition `!= false` will evaluate as `false` - in other words...

```php
$email_domain = 'b-mail.online';

if ( strpos( $email_domain, 'b-mail.online' ) != false ) {
    // Will never reach here
}
```

...this is because `!=` is known as a [loose comparison](https://www.copterlabs.com/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/), and `0 == false`. You could use a strict comparison e.g. `!== false` but in this case you don't even need `strpos` since you're checking fully-qualified domain names. Just do something like:

```php
$blocked_domains = [
    'b-mail.online',
    // Other domain names
];

if ( in_array( $email_domain, $blocked_domains, true ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'email_error', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Domain not allowed.' );
}
```